# Why core data doesn't delete related objects?

Tags: swift, core-data, nsmanagedobject, nsmanagedobjectcontext

Entities `Driver` and `Car` are in 1:Many relationship.
In `Driver` entity in relationship table I have
relationshipName, Car and No inverse
When I open table graph style in xcode between entities there are two arrows on the `car` entity and no arrows on the `driver` entity.
This is my code for deleting object:

```
let someCar:NSManagedObject = ...
let ed = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Driver", inManagedObjectContext: context!);        
        managedObjectContext?.deleteObject(someCar);
context?.save(nil);
```

But this only delete `Driver` car is intact.
What could be the reason for not deleting related objects?

Comment: What is your delete rule in your relationship?

Comment: `Cascade`. Sorry I forgot to mention that.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdRelationships.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001857-SW1

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdCreateMOs.html

Comment: Not having an inverse relationship can cause problems. There is no reason not to define the inverse relationships.

Comment: Add the inverse relationship and let us know if there are still problem

Comment: I have added `inverse relationship`. Set `cascade` delete rule again. Regenerated `NSManaged` objects. In designer now there is one arrow at `Driver` object and two arrows at `Car` object ( `Driver <-->> Car` ). And still only `Driver` is removed on delete. Is my code for delete fine? Am I missing something?

Comment: is it your delete code correct? I mean you get a car then a driver and then delete the car?

Comment: May be you are not saving your Core Data Context after deletion and stops app using XCode "stop" button?

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of the Core Data model?

Comment: Sorry. In the end it was very stupid error. Developer that wrote saving functions saved objects separated with two context objects. So objects were not related.